# Instantiating an object inside of view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to instantiate an object from inside of my view:

In my model I have an entity object called Listing that has a Property object inside of it:

```
public class Listing
{
    ...

    public Property ListingProperty { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Inside of my view I am referencing the listing model:

```
@model Realintory.Models.Listing

...
```

Inside of a form in this view I am trying to set up the properties of the "Property" object like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListingProperty.Address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListingProperty.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListingProperty.Address)
    </div>
</div>
```

This throws a null value exception because it hasn't been instantiated. My question is how do I set this up, I know this must be easy but no matter what I try it's not working on the view side.

Things like this fail badly:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   Property toCreate = new Property();
   @Model.ListingProperty = toCreate;
   ...


}
```

I realize this is probably a newb question but I cant seem to find the answer anywhere so I didn't want to waste anymore time and figured I would ask.

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize a model property in the View? Its the job of the controller to provide required data to the View. And the view is supposed to render it. There might be exception when you need data which is not tied in the model. In that case you use `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to get the data in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is supposed to provide a model that represents the data required by the view.  If the view needs that property populated in the model then it's the responsibility of the controller to do it.  The view should be using the model, not building it.

To add an arbitrary block of code in a Razor view you can do this:

```
@{
    // ...
}
```

In this case, maybe something like this is appropriate:

```
@if (Model.ListingProperty == null)
{
    Model.ListingProperty = new Property();
}
```

Comment: Ok that is fair but this is on the on-create view for this particular model and I cannot change that now.

Comment: You should change the action if you possibly can.  I'm not sure why you would be able to change the view and not the action but I've added some code snippets to my answer that may be useful.